# find CPU usage and memory usage when I execution a SSIS package with large amount of data

Tags: sql-server, ssis, query-optimization, database-administration, ssis-2012

I have a a SSIS package , package fetch data from respective table and in this package I have scripts task which generate a PDF to show the data.

I have total 50 million row count in that table,

when I executed my package its takes 60 min to generate 500 rows PDF.
I just wants that how to find CPU usage and memory usage when I execution a SSIS package for full data.

Comment: like Perfmon counters?  https://ellynguyen.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/ssis-performance-counter/